# vba-loop skip 7th day in a list

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to populate a row of cells in a Calendar kind of way, where I skip the 7th Cell, that is the Sunday. The loop should continue writting values than on Monday or the 8th Cell. And So on for every week. The ranges of the cells varies depending on the given number of Days.

I tried setting my skipping condition using MOD for every 7th Day with the Loop value. `MOD(number, divisor) = 0`.
If that checks out, no values should be added on the 7th cell but on the 8th.

The problem comes after the first sunday . My LoopValue is one "value" behind because of the offset.
When it comes to the second sunday the condition is already one step behind, skipping the cells not on Sunday (14th day) but on Monday (16th) Day
[image]

I then tried "hard coding" the condition, to skip every 7,13,19,25,31,37th Day.. but it worked until the 25th Day.
[image]

```
Sub t1_Sunday4()
Dim in1Days, in2Value, jj1 As Integer
Dim os_skip, os_New As Integer
Dim x_ShortCondt As Boolean
os_New = 1
in1Days = Range("A3")
in2Value = Range("B3")

Sub t1()
  Dim in1Days, in2Value, jj1 As Integer
  Dim os_skip, os_New As Integer
  Dim x_ShortCondt As Boolean
  os_New = 1
  in1Days = Range("A3")
  in2Value = Range("B3")
  x_ShortCondt = False


For jj1 = 1 To in1Days
Cells(5, 5 + jj1) = jj1 ' # Iteration

If x_ShortCondt = True Then

    'MOD CONDITION
    If (jj1 Mod 7) = 0 Then ' Condition for every 7th Day
        os_skip = jj1 / 7
        os_New = jj1 + os_skip 'Off Set Cell number
    End If
    
Else

    'HARD CODING THE CONDITION
    If jj1 = 7 Or jj1 = 13 Or jj1 = 19 Or jj1 = 25 _
    Or jj1 = 31 Or jj1 = 37 Or jj1 = 37 Or jj1 = 43 _
    Or jj1 = 49 Then
        os_skip = jj1 / 7
        os_New = jj1 + os_skip
    End If
    
End If
   'POPULATE CELLS
    Cells(3, 5 + os_New) = in2Value ' Value to add in cell
    
    ' CONTROL LOOP AND OFFSET VALUES
    Cells(6, 5 + os_New) = jj1      ' Iteration for said Value after Offset
    Cells(7, 5 + os_New) = os_New   ' Value for Offset
    os_New = os_New + 1

Next jj1
End Sub
```

Comment: you can use the IF an d WEEKDAY functions to check if the day is Sunday and skip:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/weekday-function-60e44483-2ed1-439f-8bd0-e404c190949a

Comment: Looking at your hard coded condition, there seems to be an error in your "mental calendar" ;). If the first sunday is on the 7th day, then the next sunday is on the 14th and the following sundays are on the 21st, 28th ... and so on. But you have hard coded the 7th, 13th, 19th, and so on in 6 days intervals after the 7th.

If you also need to track number of non-Sunday days then I suggest you use a separate counter variable for those as there are no simple formula to convert a day_number of a date to an ordinal that skips Sundays. Increment that variable on all other days but not on Sundays.

Comment: Is cell C3 value has something to do to what cell with in2Value should start ? If not (which means: in2Value will always start in cell F3, then maybe you can just do-loop until the countA in range D3:XFD3 = in2Value. For example : `Set oFill = Range("F3")` ---> the in2Value will always start in cell F3. Then have i for counting `i = 1`. Then loop `do` ... `If i Mod 7 <> 0 Then oFill.Value = in2Value` Then `If Application.CountA(Range("D3:XFD3")) = in1Days Then Exit Do` . Then offset the oFill and add the i ---> `Set oFill = oFill.Offset(0, 1): i = i + 1` ... `loop`

Comment: Hi! A word about your definitions. There is usually no reasons in using `Integer`s instead of `Long`s (no real gains in size or speed), and the type is only applied to the last variable of the line (you should use `Dim in1Days As long, in2Value As long, jj1 As Long`if you want to give a type to all variables on a line.)

Comment: But if 02.07.2024 in C3 means that in2Value should start in G3 (assumed 02.07.2024 is 2 july 2024) ... or if assumed 02.07.2024 is 7 February 2024 so in2Value shoud start in L3 **but** it can't because 7 Feb is the 7th day of February, so it must skip the 7th cell, put in2Value starting in M3. Is that the case of your situation ? Please CMIIW.

Comment: Sorry, in my first comment - I mean : ` just do-loop until the countA in range F3:XFD3 = in1Days` and 'If Application.CountA(Range("F3:XFD3")) = in1Days Then Exit Do'

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, tips and solutions! Really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below assumed that the condition is something like this :
in1Days value = 17
in2Value value = 10 
Put in2Value as many as in1Days, starting from cell F3 to the next column (same row) but skip every 7th cell

So the result of the sub (based on the example above) is like this:
F3:K3 value is 10 (there are six of 10), L3 blank, M3:R3 value is 10 (there are six of 10), S3 blank, T3:X3 value 10 (there are five of 10)... total 10 from F3:XFD3 is 17.

Another example:
in1Days value = 9
in2Value value = 10 
So the result of the sub (based on the example above) is like this:
F3:K3 value is 10 (there are six of 10), L3 blank, M3:O3 value is 10 (there are three of 10),  total 10 from F3:XFD3 is 9.

```
Sub test()
Dim in1Days As Integer, in2Value As Integer, i As Integer, oFill As Range

Range("F3:XFD3").ClearContents
in1Days = 9 'Range("A3")
in2Value = 10 'range("B3")
Set oFill = Range("F3")
i = 1

Do
    If i Mod 7 <> 0 Then oFill.Value = in2Value
    If Application.CountA(Range("F3:XFD3")) = in1Days Then Exit Do
    Set oFill = oFill.Offset(0, 1): i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

From the 2nd example, 
the first until the 6th iteration will put value 10 into F3:K3. Then on the 7th iteration (when i = 7), because 7 mod 7 = 0, it just offset the oFill and add the i. So L3 is blank (the 7th iteration, i = 7). the countA in F3:XFD3 = 6, so it won't exit the Do. Have the oFill offset(0,1) and i + 1

Now the oFill is M3 and i = 8. Because 8 mod 7 <> 0 so it put 10 into oFill
Now the countA in F3:XFD3 = 7 <> in1Days, so it won't exit the Do.
Have the oFill offset(0,1) and i + 1

Now the oFill is N3 and i = 9. Because 9 mod 7 <> 0 so it put 10 into oFill
the countA in F3:XFD3 = 8 <> in1Days , so it won't exit the Do.
Have the oFill offset(0,1) and i + 1

Now the oFill is O3 and i = 10. Because 10 mod 7 <> 0 so it put 10 into oFill
the countA in F3:XFD3 = 9 = in1Days, so it exit the Do and exit the sub

Below is the sample result if in1Days value is 31 
[image]

To test, just change in1Days and in2Value with different value.
But that if I understand you correctly.

---

To skip two cells after writing the in2Value to 5 cells....

```
Sub test2()
Dim in1Days As Integer, in2Value As Integer, i As Integer, oFill As Range

Range("F3:XFD3").ClearContents
in1Days = 27 'Range("A3")
in2Value = 10 'range("B3")
Set oFill = Range("F3")
f = 5: s = 2

Do
    For i = 1 To f
        oFill.Value = in2Value
        Set oFill = oFill.Offset(0, 1)
        If Application.CountA(Range("F3:XFD3")) = in1Days Then Exit Sub
    Next i
    Set oFill = oFill.Offset(0, s)
Loop

End Sub
```

This is another approach without using `mod`.
f variable is the how many cells to be filled, s variable is how many cells to be skipped.

Again, I'm very sorry as I still don't understand what you mean about weekday, nth day of the month, the connection of 02.07.2024 in cell C3 with the macro process to achieve the result. And 02.07.2024 in cell C3 is dd.mm.yyyy ? or is it mm.dd.yyyy ?

Please note, the two codes in my answer doesn't relate to any date/day/week of a certain month of a certain year at all. It's just a very simple command something like :

> write in2Value as many as in1Days starting from cell F3 to the next
> column (same row) for N times (5 in the example code) then skip the column N times (2 in the example code) then
> continue writing to the next column if the countA in F3:XFD3
> has not reach in1Days value.

Below is the result where in1Days = 31, f = 5 and s = 2.
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for you answer. I'll make sure to check it out tomorrow.
I was wondering, based on your solution, would it be possible now to skip saturdays and sundays altogether? That means, populating 5 cells and skipping two. Again based on a number of given days. I tried with the WeekDay function, but not sure how to include the outcome inside the loop to skip every false statement (Saturday, Sunday) for any given number of Days.  
F2 = 03.04.2023.    =IF(WEEKDAY(F2;2)<6;"WeekDay";"False")

Comment: to populate 5 cells and skip 2 cells, please have a look to my updated answer. But again, the thing which I don't understand is you say about date and day of the month ---> _skip every false statement (**Saturday, Sunday**)_ ---> this is the thing which confused me. Because the code I provide it's about _skip every false statement (**the 6th and the 7th cell**)_ Please CMIIW. Also I'm sorry as I don't understand this `F2 = 03.04.2023. =IF(WEEKDAY(F2;2)<6;"WeekDay";"False")`

Comment: Thanks again for your Update on skipping 2 Cells. It worked perfect. So simple and yet so precise. I was getting confused setting the loop with different conditions. 
I was a bit unclear sorry. Saturday and Sunday were for me to the 6th and 7th cell.

Comment: Hi, so I was trying to update your "skip 2 cells" method to loop through a set of values in Column A.  But I keep getting an error on "oFill = oFill.Offset(0, s)"  
I can't post the whole Code here as a single Comment so I'll try with different replies.

<pre> <code>
Sub LoopS1()
Dim in1Days As Integer, in2Value As Integer
Dim osii1, osjj1 As Integer
Dim ii1 As Integer, myUBound As Integer
Dim i As Integer, f As Integer, s As Integer, oFill As Range

Range("F3:XFD6").ClearContents

osii1 = 2  'Offset Row
osjj1 = 5  'Offset Column
f = 5: s = 2
myUBound = 2
</code></pre>

Comment: I really can't get to format my comments so it shows as a code  Block. 
Tried with :
<pre> <code>   ... </code></pre> ;  
the "four spaces"    ;  
the  “code fences”  ```   ;   
.I think it might be easier if I just post a new question with my code and screenshots

Answer (score 1):

To save my workbook each week as a backup, I use the following:

```
If Weekday(Now) = (vbMonday) Or Day(Now) = 1 Then
        TodayDate = Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD")
        wbB.SaveAs Filename:= _
            pathName & TodayDate & " Backup.xlsx", _
            FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
End If
```

and haven't encountered any issues so far.
So in your case perhaps something like

'assign the dates to an array (your F2:AN2)
If Not Weekday(yourDates(jji)) = 1 Then 'should work the same according to the documentation as comparing it to vbSunday
'your code here
End If

It's also better to write an array in one go to your range (and reverse) instead of looping through a range and writing per iteration to your range.

To fit your mod-idea instead of dates, would this be something you're going for? Doesn't quite match yet with your first picture but it does the skipping properly. (getting more busy at work rn so will fix later if required)

```
Sub t1()
    Dim in1Days As Integer, in2Value As Integer, jj1 As Integer 'watch out with declaring your variables, "As Integer" has to be with every variable
    Dim os_New As Integer
    Dim skipD As Integer
    os_New = 0
    in1Days = Range("A3")
    in2Value = Range("B3")
    Dim arr()
    Dim maxCol As Integer
    maxCol = in1Days + in1Days \ 7 'in1Days \ 7 gives the division while discarding the rest
    ReDim arr(1 To 5, 1 To maxCol)
    
    For jj1 = 1 To in1Days
        arr(3, jj1 + skipD) = jj1 + skipD ' # Iteration
        
        'MOD CONDITION
        If (jj1 + skipD) Mod 7 = 0 Then
            skipD = skipD + 1
            arr(3, jj1 + skipD) = jj1 + skipD
        Else
            os_New = os_New + 1 'amount of cells that aren't a 7th day
        End If
        arr(1, jj1 + skipD) = in2Value
        arr(4, jj1 + skipD) = os_New
        arr(5, jj1 + skipD) = jj1 + skipD 'same as #iterations so kinda useless here
    Next jj1
    
    'POPULATE CELLS
    Range("F3").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr 'write it in one go
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

To skip the Saturday/Sunday (or 6th and 7th day depending on what you're going with):

```
Sub t1()
    Dim in1Days As Integer, in2Value As Integer, jj1 As Integer 'watch out with declaring your variables, "As Integer" has to be with every variable
    Dim os_New As Integer
    Dim skipD As Integer
    os_New = 0
    in1Days = Range("A3")
    in2Value = Range("B3")
    Dim arr()
    Dim maxCol As Integer
    maxCol = in1Days + 3 * (in1Days \ 6) 'in1Days \ 7 gives the division while discarding the rest
    ReDim arr(1 To 5, 1 To maxCol)
    
    For jj1 = 1 To in1Days
        arr(3, jj1 + skipD) = jj1 + skipD ' # Iteration
        
        'MOD CONDITION
        If (jj1 + skipD + 1) Mod 7 = 0 Then 'check if the weekend is about
            skipD = skipD + 1
            arr(3, jj1 + skipD) = jj1 + skipD
            skipD = skipD + 1
            arr(3, jj1 + skipD) = jj1 + skipD
        End If
        os_New = os_New + 1 'amount of cells that aren't a 7th day
        arr(1, jj1 + skipD) = in2Value
        arr(4, jj1 + skipD) = os_New
        arr(5, jj1 + skipD) = jj1 + skipD 'same as #iterations so kinda useless here
    Next jj1
    ReDim Preserve arr(1 To 5, 1 To jj1 - 1 + skipD)
    'POPULATE CELLS
    Range("F3").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr 'write it in one go
End Sub
```

To use the `Weekday()` there really isn't much to change about the code. It only needs the startcode which is in C3 and since it has the value of `02/07/2024` which is a Tuesday, you'll notice a different outcome with 4 weekdays to start with (unlike the previous one where you started off with 5 days). I have tested with 40 days and had no error/issue.

```
Sub t1Weekday()
    Dim in1Days As Integer, in2Value As Integer, jj1 As Integer 'watch out with declaring your variables, "As Integer" has to be with every variable
    Dim os_New As Integer, skipD As Integer, sDate As Date
    os_New = 0
    in1Days = Range("A3")
    in2Value = Range("B3")
    sDate = Range("C3").Value
    Dim arr(), amt As Integer
    Dim maxCol As Integer
    maxCol = in1Days + 3 * (in1Days \ 6) 'in1Days \ 7 gives the division while discarding the rest
    ReDim arr(1 To 5, 1 To maxCol)
    
    For jj1 = 1 To in1Days
        arr(3, jj1 + skipD) = jj1 + skipD ' # Iteration
        
        'MOD CONDITION
        If Weekday(sDate + jj1 + skipD - 1) = 7 Then 'check if the weekend is about
        '-1 is needed since jj1 starts at 1, could also have taken 1 from sDate before the for loop
        ' Weekday() = 7 is for Saturday when the default start of the week is Sunday
            skipD = skipD + 1
            arr(3, jj1 + skipD) = jj1 + skipD
            skipD = skipD + 1
            arr(3, jj1 + skipD) = jj1 + skipD
        End If
        os_New = os_New + 1 'amount of cells that aren't a 7th day
        arr(1, jj1 + skipD) = in2Value
        arr(4, jj1 + skipD) = os_New
        arr(5, jj1 + skipD) = jj1 + skipD 'same as #iterations so kinda useless here
    Next jj1
    ReDim Preserve arr(1 To 5, 1 To jj1 - 1 + skipD)
    'POPULATE CELLS
    Range("F3").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr 'write it in one go
End Sub
```

If you have any questions, feel free to ask

Comment: Thanks so much for your time and your answer! Will read carefully your suggestion tomorrow early.  The skipping is the most important part. 
On that note, building up from your suggestion, would it be possible to skip saturdays and sundays altogether? That means, populating 5 cells and skipping two. Again based on a number of given days.
I tried with the WeekDay function, but not sure how to include that on the loop to skip every false statement (Saturday, Sunday).

F2 = 03.04.2023
=IF(WEEKDAY(F2;2)<6;"WeekDay";"False")

Comment: Wouldn't see why you couldn't skip 2 days, I'll try adjusting the code tomorrow. The `Weekday()` functionality would require a starting date, if C3 is yours, then I'll see to give you an example on that as well.

Comment: In case you didn't notice, see my Edit for the update of 5 days (and with Weekday()) @jjjhhh

Comment: Hi ! I'm sorry, I just saw your updates. Thanks again for your edits regarding the Weekdays condition. It was really helpful. Is there anyway to Start and fill the cells based on the starting Date of my Data-in your example (sDate = Range("C3").Value) ? This For the DUration - in1Days = Range("A3") - and skipping Saturdays and Sundays? Thanks again

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, the second sub (t1Weekday) is based on your start date that's in C3. `If Weekday(sDate + jj1 + skipD - 1) = 7 Then` starts checking at the startdate and the code basically continues from there onward.